# DEQ with two Variables and one Parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I find a genereal solution of this equation:

$(\frac{d \tau}{d t})^2=(\frac{d \theta}{d t})^2+a^2$

Is this the genereal solution ?

$\frac{d \tau}{d t}=\omega$

$\frac{d \theta}{d t}=\sqrt{\omega^2-a^2}$

resulting in:

$(\frac{\tau-\tau_0}{t-t_0 })^2=(\frac{\theta-\theta_0}{t-t_0 })^2+a^2$